# Push notification not showing message body when app is killed. it only shows default icon of app

Tags: push-notification, android-notifications

when my app is running is receive notification along with title message and app icon like this
[image]

but when my  is killed it does not shoe message body only shows icon and title which is applications name like this

[image]

while the code for my OnMessagerecieved method is this

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        String from = message.getFrom();
        Map data = message.getData();


        datarecieved = message;




        String orderIds= "";
        try {
            if(data.get("accountId")!=null)
                orderIds = data.get("accountId").toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String userId=SharedPrefsUtils.getStringPreference(getApplicationContext(),"user_id");

        if(userId!=null&&userId.length()>0) {
            if (orderIds.equals("-101")) {
                generateNotificationForOrder(getApplicationContext(), data);
            } else if (!orderIds.equals("")) {
                generateNotification(getApplicationContext(), data);
            }
        }


    }
```

while my JSON for notification is like this

{
   "to": "fcm_token",
   "data": {
       "type": "101 / 102 / 103",
       "msg": "CustomerId",
       "id": "0",
       "accountId": "-101"
   },
   "content_available": true
}

Comment: can you share your JSON payload that sending via Firebase?

Comment: @iravulI have added JSON payload in my question now. kindly check it